# ng2-smart-table: data from json

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I would like to link my json data to ng2-smart-table

My json return a lot of datas

```
"data":{
   "name":"Myname",
   "email":"myemail@gmail.com",
   "car":[
      {
       "carId":"99",
       "carName":"mycar",
       "carBurant":"diesel"
      },
      {
       "carId":"88",
       "carName":"mycar2",
       "carBurant":"diesel"
      },
      {
       "carId":"77",
       "carName":"mycar3",
       "carBurant":"diesel",
      },
   ]
 }
```

I would like to put "carId" , "carName" and "carBurant" on my ng2-smart-table
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite straight-forward if you happen to get a chance to have a look at the [**documentation**](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation) here.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  settings = {
    columns: {
      carId: {
        title: "Car ID"
      },
      carName: {
        title: "Car Name"
      },
      carBurant: {
        title: "Car Burant"
      }
    }
  };
  data;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get("assets/user.json").subscribe(user => (this.data = user.car));
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<ng2-smart-table 
  [settings]="settings"
  [source]="data">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-smart-table-eg) for your ref.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. 
I used this documention but I still had a problem. I found, I did not import the good data in my array. sorry

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy Jamming. 